# How to create multiple folders in same directory in Java

Tags: java

I have a folder named Files and I need to create multiple folders inside Files like Iteration_1, Iteration_2, Iteration_3 etc. 
Every time I run the script, a new folder should be created.

I was able to create the folder in first Iteration and nothing is created in second iteration.

```
File newFile=new File(iteration);
newFile.mkdir();
if(newFile.exists())
{
    String folderName=destFolder+"\\"+"Iteration_"+count+"_"+sdf.format(new Date());
    File nf=new File(folderName);
    nf.mkdir();
    count++;
}
```

Here iteration is the folder that I'm reading from properties files.

Could someone help me with this?

My Folder structure -

```
Story 1 (Parent Folder)
    -Iteration (sub folder)
    -Iteration_1
    -Iteration_2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple directories given the folder names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739128/how-to-create-multiple-directories-given-the-folder-names)

Comment: @DangNguyen I have checked that as well. Didn't get a solution.

Comment: where is your loop?

Comment: what is destFolder variable here  ? new folders are going to be created inside destFolder

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41314370/14955

Comment: Yes, destFolder is my parent folder. I want Iteration, Iteration_1, Iteration_2 etc inside my destFolder. That is my variable name that I'm reading from my properties file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the reason you're not making more directories/folders is because the code is only executed once. Try this instead:

```
int count = 1; //or whatever
while(newFile.exists()) {
    String folderName=destFolder+"\\"+"Iteration_"+count+"_"+sdf.format(new Date());
    File nf=new File(folderName);
    nf.mkdir();
    count++;
}
```

This way it will repeatedly create new files while the condition `newFile.exists()` is true, which judging by your code, will be forever (possibly).

If you only want 100 folders, from 1 to 100 inclusive, use the following:

```
for(int count = 1; count <= 100; count++) { //start from 1, go to 100
    String folderName=destFolder+"\\"+"Iteration_"+count+"_"+sdf.format(new Date());
    File nf=new File(folderName);
    nf.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: I want to create a new folder every time i run the script and not create many folders at once.